# UIImageview disappear when its inside a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, uibezierpath

I Have a custom xib created along with a UIBezierpath, and when I add an image to the closed section of that UIBezierCurve, the image is not showing. Is there a way to add an image on top of the UIBezierpath's closed section.

**The image should display in the white section**

[image]

Code as bellow

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  
         let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(TableViewCells.ForgotPwCell.rawValue, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ForgetPasswordTableViewCell
         let shape = Utils.drawBazierCurve(width: tableView.frame.width, height: tableView.frame.height)
         cell.contentView.layer.addSublayer(shape)
         let theImage = UIImage(named: "forgot_pw.png") // create a UIImage
         cell.forgotpwImageVw.image = theImage
        return cell
  
}
```

Path creation method as bellow

```
static func drawBazierCurve(width:CGFloat,height:CGFloat) -> CAShapeLayer {

let path = UIBezierPath()

let controlPoint1 = CGPoint(x: (3/8)*width, y: (4/18)*height)
let controlPoint2 = CGPoint(x: (6/8)*width, y: (8/18)*height)
let end = CGPoint(x: width, y: (6/18)*height)

path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height/2))
path.addCurve(to: end, controlPoint1: controlPoint1, controlPoint2: controlPoint2)
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

path.close()

let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.path = path.cgPath;
shape.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

return shape
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a Second Layer on the Top of your path and set image as content in your new layer.